# Rapidgator API Direct Download Link Error

Tags: php, api

Guys, I am currently working on file hosting premium link generator basically it will be a website from where you can get a premium link of uptobox,rapidgator,uploaded.net and other file hosts sites without purchasing the premium account. Basically, We are purchasing the accounts of this website on behalf of the users and offering this service at a low price. So when I was setting up API of direct download link of rapidgator I was able to get that link but I was getting session is over. I was trying to that API via a software, not via manual coding  and I am facing this problem

So I have been getting Rapidgator API reference from  Tihs Site:- https://gist.github.com/Chak10/f097b77c32a9ce83d05ef3574a30367d

So I am doing the following Thing With My Debugging Software And I am getting success response but when I just open that URL in my browser it shows Session Id Failed.

So Here Are Steps What I am Doing
Sending a post request on https://rapidgator.net/api/user/login  with username and data and I am getting this output

```
{"response":{"session_id":"g8a13f32hr4cbbbo54qdigrcb3","expire_date":1542688501,"traffic_left":"13178268723435"},"response_status":200,"response_details":null}
```

Now I am sending a get request (I tried Post Request Too But the Same Thing Happened) on this url with session id and URL embedded in URL  https://rapidgator.net/api/file/download?sid=&url=
and I am getting this output

```
{"response":{"url":"http:\/\/pr56.rapidgator.net\/\/?r=download\/index&session_id=uB9st0rVfhX2bNgPrFUri01a9i5xmxan"},"response_status":200,"response_details":null}
```

When I try to download the file from the Url through my browser It says Invalid Session and sometimes too many open connections error

Link of the error:- https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAd1o.png
Success Response:- https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqB6d.png

Answer (score 0):

Rapidgator needs its api to be hit three times with different URLs.

```
 $cookie = $working_dir.rand();
 $headers = array("header"=>"Referer: https://rapidgator.net");

     $ch = curl_init();
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://rapidgator.net/api/user/login");
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=email@domain.ext&password=myplaintextpassword");
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
           curl_close ($ch);

 $rapidgator_json = json_decode($result,true);
 return array($rapidgator_json['response']['session_id'],$cookie);
```

http://rapidgator.net/api/user/login (this is the initial login)
Above link gives you a session id that you need. The response is in JSON

Now we need to request a download link that will allow us to download without having to log in to a human input form. So we will use its api to request a download link using the intial session id we got from the 1st url.

```
 $headers = array("header"=>"Referer: http://rapidgator.net/api/user/login");

     $ch = curl_init();
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://rapidgator.net/api/file/download?sid=$rapidgator_session&url=$rapidgator_file");
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $working_dir.$rapidgator_cookie);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $working_dir.$rapidgator_cookie);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
           curl_close ($ch);

 $rapidgator_json = json_decode($result,true);
 return array($rapidgator_json['response']['url']);
```

Basically, we pass the session id Rapidgator gave us assuming you have properly passed a valid account. Then we include the source url you had obtained (Link to file) `http://rapidgator.net/api/file/download?sid=$rapidgator_session&url=$rapidgator_file`

After that. Rapidgator will return a JSON response with an url that u can use to obtain the file in question. This allows you to use whatever download method you want
as that link is a session url is valid for a short period of time.

```
$rapidgator_json['response']['url']
```

All code above is somewhat incomplete. Some extra checks on the json responces for possible errors/limits are recommended. I used functions on my end but this is enough for you to see what you should be doing. Rapidshare API has other data that can be useful in determining if you have gone over your daily quota. How long the session url is going to last and so on.